# App get slow after time

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, animation, instruments

I am about to finish a little iOS game using only the UIKit. I am using some `UIView` animations (about 10 at a time, repeating) which after time perform really slow.

I am running it on a device. Xcode shows CPU 99% used and the memory starts at about 60MB increasing to about 240MB max, staying at that value. I am showing tons of images (but all of them are really small, ~20kB). What could be the cause of the slow animations? Is 240MB of memory usage a lot?

Comment: I once had a similar issue. And my problem was not removing the image after they are shown. So, eventually they stack up and the whole animation becomes slower and slower. Hope this gives you some idea.

Comment: 240MB seems a lot for a "little game using only UIKit". Be careful with your allocation.
If you're using ARC be careful about not keeping strong reference on unused object. If you're not using ARC, be careful about releasing unused object.

Comment: hey guys thanks for your inputs. i was able to solve my problem. i saved my small pngs width pretty big widths and heigths. ios stores these images uncompressed so my memory blew up pretty quick. so be aware not to store compressed images with to big dimensions...